# MySQL Foreign Key DDL issue

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1064, ddl

I have a problem with the last 4 lines of my DDL.
 I am trying to add 2 Foreign keys, but it isn't working.

the last four lines of my code are:

```
PRIMARY KEY personID,
FOREIGN KEY petID  REFERENCES Pets(petID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY petFoodID REFERENCES PetFood(petFoodID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
) ENGINE=Innodb;
```

Comment: The exact error I keep getting is: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY PetID REFERENCES Pets(petID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE C' at line 8

Comment: Place a `space` or `new line` between `PRIMARY KEY` and `personID`,

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the last comma, before the closing parenthesis.

```
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, ) ENGINE=Innodb;
                                   ^
```

should be:

```
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ) ENGINE=Innodb;
                                   ^
```